# what happens behind the scenes when Javascript functions are called

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain what happens in the below scenario:(this was an interview question)

```
function test(a){
    alert(a);
}

function test(a,b){
    alert(a,b);
}

function callTest(){
    test(a);
    test(a,b);
}
```

I was asked how the javascript calls the methods, and what happens behind the scenes in this scenario

Comment: What do you mean "behind the scenes"? Sounds like a pretty intense interview question. I would expect that maybe they would ask what the contents of the alert dialog would be...

Comment: `alert` only takes one argument, so the second will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test(a){     // f1. never called.
    alert(a);
}

function test(a,b){   // f2. overwrite f1 function because name of two functions is same.
    alert(a,b);
}

function callTest(){
    test(1);     // called f2 with (1, undefined)
    test(1,2);   // called f2 with (1, 2)
}
callTest();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was explained well.

Answer (score 3):

If you run it in that order, test(a) will be replaced by test(a,b)

When callTest() is run, then test(a) will alert(a, undefined), then test(a,b) will alert(a,b)

Comment: Agreed - JS don't have the concept of method overloading.